# duplicate variables outside braces

Tags: c++

My teacher gave me a question (С++):
What will be printed on the screen after:

```
{
     int a = 2;
     cout << a << endl;
     {   
         int a=7;
         cout << a << endl;
     }
     cout << ++a << endl;
}
```

And I wonder is there something complicated? Or just duplicated identifier a? Or such braces everywhere do any specific effect and it may go without error? Like in functions when variables do not exist outside. Can it be so outside the block of braces? What are these braces for?

Comment: I'm disappointed that you probably spent as much time writing up this question as it would have taken to enter the code in a text-editor, compile and run it.  By that simple act you would have taken up the challenge of running a piece of code, examining the output, and trying to understand the reason behind it.  This inquisitive drive to experiment and observe is a fundamental quality of a computer programmer.

Comment: I think the best answer to `What will be printed on the screen after:` in any situation is to run the code to see what happens.

Answer (score 6):

The braces in this case delimit the scope of the variables. The inner braces basically declare a new variable `a`, hiding the outside variable.

It's equivalent to

```
{
   int a=2;
   cout<<a<<endl;
   {   
     int b=7; cout<<b<<endl;
   }
   cout<<++a<<endl;
}
```

with the exception that `a` is not available in the inside scope.

The output would be

```
2
7
3
```

Answer (score 1):

The braces form a new scope. The variable `a` in the inner block is a different variable from the `a` in the outer block.